# C++ problem with std::pair and forward declarations

Tags: c++, utility, std-pair

Unfortunately I still got a problem with my templated code from here:

[C++ fancy template code problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911434/c-fancy-template-code-problem)

on line 49 in the file 'utility':

```
error C2440: 'Initializing': cannot convert from 'const int' to 'IntersectionData *'

error C2439: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second': member could not be initialized
```

how could i figure out where the problem is? the only place i use a pair with 'IntersectionData*' is here:

```
#include "MRMaterialMatth.h"
#include "IntersectionData.h"
using namespace std;

struct IShaderMatth {
 virtual ~IShaderMatth() {}
 vector<pair<MaterialMatth,IntersectionData*> > traceCols; 
};
```

and there are not any other compiler errors

how can I track down this?

//edit: utility is not my code. it must be from std.. the code of line 49 looks like this:

```
template<class _Other1,
    class _Other2>
    pair(const pair<_Other1, _Other2>& _Right)
    : first(_Right.first), second(_Right.second)
    {   // construct from compatible pair
    }
```

line 49 is the line of the comment

edit2:
the only places where i change something about the content of tracecols look like this:

```
            IntersectionData* iDataOut = NULL;
            if(newIData_out!=NULL)
            {
                iDataOut = new IntersectionData(*iData);
            }
            traceCols->push_back(make_pair(MaterialMatth(),iDataOut));
```

and

```
    if(traceCols){
        traceCols->push_back(make_pair(MaterialMatth(), NULL));
    }
```

and

```
        if(traceCols)
        {
            (*traceCols)[traceCols->size()].second = new IntersectionData(*newIData);
        }
```

is NULL the problem? it's a pointer, so i should be allowed to create a pair with NULL, no??

Comment: What is line 49 of utility, and where else do you use traceCols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly casting the `NULL` to `IntersectionData *` in your call to `make_pair()`.

```
if(traceCols){
        traceCols->push_back(make_pair(MaterialMatth(), (IntersectionData *)NULL));
}
```

Comment: hey yeah - that solved the Problem! but i'd be really glad if someone could explain me why this is necessary?

Comment: In Visual Studio (which I assume you're using from the error messages), `NULL` is defined as a literal `0`, so your use of `make_pair` becomes `make_pair(MaterialMatth(),0)`, of type `pair<MaterialMatth,int>`.

Comment: In fact, the C++ standard demands that `NULL` be defined as `0`, regardless of which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem initializing one of those pairs.

Ask yourself, "What initializes that?"

The answer is the vector traceCols.

Now ask, "Where am I creating elements in traceCols?"

Once you answer that, you should know what is going wrong.

Comment: could be the problem that i create a pair with NULL? NULL probably is a const int..

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for the line `(*traceCols)[traceCols->size()].second = new IntersectionData(*newIData)` - it seems like that would go out of the vector's bounds (since the largest index of a vector is `size() - 1`).

I'm not sure if the NULL is causing it - so comment out that line, and see for yourself (or try Dave's suggestion)! If it doesn't work, comment out another. Eventually, you'll either find what line, and be able to ask a more specific question, or it'll be none of those things, and you'll know you have to search somewhere else. That's what I do when I see all these silly compiler error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an assignment somewhere from a `pair<MaterialMatth,int>`.  The compiler is trying to convert from that to the declaration you listed, but it can't convert from an int to a pointer without an explicit cast.